# iOS Parse.com saving object with a pointer column gives "user not allowed" error

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I'm trying to update an existing row in my Parse.com class from an iOS app. Upon doing so, I'm getting this error back from Parse:

```
This user is not allowed to perform the update operation on City. You can change this setting in the Data Browser. (Code: 119, Version: 1.9.1)
```

I have two Parse.com classes: `City` and `Bar`. The `City` class is read-only (it's a list of cities that won't change) and the `Bar` class is the class that users interact with (like adding comments, ratings, menu items, etc). `Bar` has a `Pointer` column on `City` and the permissions on `Bar` are all on for the public user.

Here's a snippet of code:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
  [super viewWillAppear:animated];
  PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Bar"];
  self.bar = [query getObjectWithId:self.barId];
  self.bar.name = @"Foo";
  [self.bar saveInBackground];
}
```

Some notes about the snippet: I'm passing in the bar's ID from the previous view controller via segue. I also know this is running the Parse query on the main thread and it's going to block...I'm simply prototyping right now and this is meaningless code.

Upon running that snippet, I get the error listed above.  As you can see in the code, I'm not changing the city value nor am I even including it in the query results. I don't understand why I would be getting this error. Any input would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It seems you are going to have problems because you are not waiting for [query getObjectWithId:self.barId] to finish. So using self.bar before it's ready will likely fail. It may not be exactly your question, but I thought it may be useful for you.

Comment: It looks like this issue is due to me instantiating my `City` object using `objectWithoutDataWithClassName`. It seems that instantiating an object in this manner sets the dirty flag as true. So when I save my `Bar` it's also trying to save my `City` because it's dirty. But `City` is read-only and hence the error.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code and see if the 2 NSLog messages appear in the order you expect:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Bar"];
    //self.bar = [query getObjectWithId:self.barId];
    [query getObjectInBackgroundWithId:self.barId block:^(PFObject *result, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"query has finished.");
        self.bar = result[0];
    }];
    self.bar.name = @"Foo";
    NSLog(@"Now going to saveInBackground.");
    [self.bar saveInBackground];
}
```

And then try this, I think it may work, though I do not know all the details of your project:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Bar"];
    //self.bar = [query getObjectWithId:self.barId];
    [query getObjectInBackgroundWithId:self.barId block:^(PFObject *result, NSError *error) {
        self.bar = result[0]; // or result; ??
        self.bar.name = @"Foo";
        [self.bar saveInBackground];
    }];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Take a look at my comment to my original question. Turns out using `objectWithoutDataWithClassName` sets the dirty flag (which is what I was using to generate my `City` object). Now that I'm pulling the values from Parse (rather than generating them myself) it all works as expected.